# On official LoaderManager example filtering... Why the MySearchView?

Tags: android

I am studying the things around LoaderManager, and I am trying to fix the similar functionality in my own application the proposed way. I have found several details that are not clear to me. It could be the case the code is extracted from something bigger, and the details are the unneccessary extra features for the example. It could also be the case I simply overlooked the reason...

**Firstly**, the example introduces

```
public static class MySearchView extends SearchView...
```

that overrides the `onActionViewCollapsed` only to clear the query. What is the reason?

**Secondly**, the `mCurFilter` is initialized to `null` and tested against `null` in `onQueryTextChange` and `onCreateLoader`. Would not be the empty string better, more robust, and leading to a simpler implementation than the `null` for the indication? To be concrete, the `onQueryTextChange` is implemented as:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
    // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
    // with this filter.
    String newFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;

    // Don't do anything if the filter hasn't actually changed.
    // Prevents restarting the loader when restoring state.
    if (mCurFilter == null && newFilter == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (mCurFilter != null && mCurFilter.equals(newFilter)) {
        return true;
    }
    mCurFilter = newFilter;
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    return true;
}
```

Why the `newText` is converted to `newFilter` (as `null` for empty strings) and then the complicated comparisons to `null` values *and* non-null values is done. Could not it be implemented simply as folows (the original comments where preserved)?

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
    // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
    // with this filter.

    // Don't do anything if the filter hasn't actually changed.
    // Prevents restarting the loader when restoring state.
    if (mCurFilter.equals(newText)) {
        return true;
    }
    mCurFilter = newText;
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    return true;
}
```

The `onCreateLoader` couuld test for `mCurFilter.isEmpty()` instead of `mCurFilter == null`.

Thanks for your time and experience.